How can I optimize performance for my Pandas Agent using OpenAI Azure and LangChain?
I have implemented a Pandas Agent using OpenAI Azure and LangChain to handle queries on a dataset. However, I'm encountering performance issues where a simple query takes between 8-12 seconds to execute. Here's a simplified version of my current setup:
import pandas as pd
from time import time
from openai_tools import create_pandas_dataframe_agent

   

 # Data import
    csv_dir_path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/master/titanic.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_dir_path)
    
    # Creating Pandas Agent
    agent_executor = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
        model,
        df,
        verbose=True,
        agent_type="openai-tools", 
        max_iterations=5
    )
    
    def agent_query(question):
        time_start = time()
        res = agent_executor.invoke({"input": question})
        time_finish = time()
        print("Query execution time:", time_finish - time_start, "seconds")
        return res['output']
    
    # Example query
    question = 'whats the percentage of male survivors'
    agent_query(question)

Issues:
Performance Delay: Queries take 8-12 seconds to complete, even though sometimes the response is ready earlier.
Attempted Solutions: I've tried adjusting max_iterations without noticeable impact on response time. Profiling suggests the delay might be due to data loading or model invocation.
Desired Outcome:
I'm seeking advice on optimizing the setup to improve query response time.
Any suggestions on improving efficiency or identifying bottlenecks would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
Here is an output that I get regulary:
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...

Invoking: `python_repl_ast` with `{'query': "male_survivors = df[(df['Sex'] == 'male') & (df['Survived'] == 1)].shape[0]\ntotal_males = df[df['Sex'] == 'male'].shape[0]\npercentage_male_survivors = (male_survivors / total_males) * 100\npercentage_male_survivors"}`


18.890814558058924The percentage of male survivors is approximately 18.89%.

> Finished chain.
9.06292200088501

